# Unable to run Access query through ADODB connection in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am trying to paste in the results of an access query to a sheet in Excel.

When I run the following code, nothing happens. No errors or warnings, just nothing ever gets pasted in. However, when I run the same code, but use a table instead of a query name, it successfully pulls in the table. But when I replace it with a query name, it returns nothing.

In the past I have done the same thing but instead of calling the query name, I have stored the SQL query as a string within the macro and called the query by referencing the string. I tried that and that did not work in this case.

The query I am trying to pull references other queries as tables, and I think this is why I am having issues. Like I said, I have pulled data from Access with this code many times before but have only been able to do so when I am referencing tables only, and not queries.

```
Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
Set Con = New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim iCols As Integer

Set Con = New ADODB.Connection

With Con
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.Open AccessDBPath
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "query1", Con

Sheets("NAHV").Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

I have tried replacing the rs.Open line with the Execute command:

```
Set rs = Con.Execute("query1")
```

and this also did not work.

I have also tried replacing the full block with

```
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
Dim myFile As String: myFile = AccessDBPath
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & myFile & ";"
    .Open
End With
Set rs = cn.Execute("query1")

Sheets("NAHV").Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

and this did not work either.

Comment: Does the query return any data in Access itself?

Comment: Yes, it runs with no problem in Access and returns data.

Comment: Ok, then I am sorry I do not know. I tested your first code and it is working for me fine. I tested with a query which contains two tables.

Comment: To clarify, the issue is not that the query contains more than one table. The issue (I think) is that the query contains other queries.

Comment: I also tested with a query containing other queries

Comment: Can you try with the query `SELECT * FROM query1;`? I believe it's anticipating an sql statement and `query1` is not sql, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Works as well. But why would you want to do it like that?

Comment: I've run into a similar issue to what @JNevill describes. VBA seems to have a weird hang-up where it thinks all SQL needs to begin with a `select` statement. Running Oracle queries, for example, it refuses to allow you to run `with x as (...) select * from x`. Instead, you have to wrap the whole thing in a select, like `select * from (with x as (...) select * from x)`

Comment: It may depend. I haven't had any issue with pushing SQL through ADODB that doesn't start with `SELECT` since I often `CALL` a procedure or execute commands. It could be that running sql through the front end as a data source might have that hang up though. OTherwise it would be up to the ODBC driver that is set in your ADODB connection string. I have, personally, never just stuck a table or a view name into the `open` method of a `ADODB.Recordset` object, so maybe that works, it just doesn't feel right though.

Comment: Please show content of *query1*. I am unable to reproduce your results with either code block methods using a saved query referencing other queries.